# Swift Json data Decoding

Tags: ios, json

I'm going to decode the data in the json file.
For the json file below, how do I configure Decodable Structures?
If you've printed data only.
An error is coming out ex)

> error == keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "name", intValue: nil) ("name").", underlyingError: nil))

However, byte is also output.
Please teach me the way.

ViewController

```
class ChampViewController: UIViewController{
    
    let url = "https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.19.1/data/en_US/champion.json"
    
    let collectionView : UICollectionView = {
       let flowlayout = CarLensCollectionViewLayout()
       let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: flowlayout)
       return cv
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        riot()
    }
    func riot(){
        guard let riotURL = URL(string: url) else { return }
        let riotSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = riotSession.dataTask(with: riotURL) { data, reponds, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            if let safeData = data {
                self.parsonRiotJson(riotData: safeData)
                print(safeData)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    func parsonRiotJson(riotData:Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do{
          let decoderData = try decoder.decode(ChampionDecodable.self, from: riotData)
            print(decoderData.data)
        }catch {
            print("error == \(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

Decodable File

```
import Foundation


struct ChampionDecodable : Decodable {
    let data : Champion
}

struct Champion : Decodable {
    let name : [String:String]
}
```

JsonFile

```
{
    "type": "champion",
    "format": "standAloneComplex",
    "version": "11.16.1",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "11.16.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade",
            "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
            "info": {
                "attack": 8,
                "defense": 4,
                "magic": 3,
                "difficulty": 4
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Aatrox.png",
                "sprite": "champion0.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            },
            "tags": [
                "Fighter",
                "Tank"
            ],
            "partype": "Blood Well",
            "stats": {
                "hp": 580,
                "hpperlevel": 90,
                "mp": 0,
                "mpperlevel": 0,
                "movespeed": 345,
                "armor": 38,
                "armorperlevel": 3.25,
                "spellblock": 32,
                "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
                "attackrange": 175,
                "hpregen": 3,
                "hpregenperlevel": 1,
                "mpregen": 0,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0,
                "crit": 0,
                "critperlevel": 0,
                "attackdamage": 60,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 5,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 2.5,
                "attackspeed": 0.651
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is no key `name` on the `Aatrox` level which is true.

You have to declare the structs this way

```
struct ChampionDecodable : Decodable {
    let data : [String:Champion]
}

struct Champion : Decodable {
    let name : String
    let title : String?
}
```

Comment: 당신의 말 그대로 따라하였다.
하지만 keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "tittle", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Malzahar", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"tittle\", intValue: nil) (\"tittle\").", underlyingError: nil))
오류는 여전히 뜨는중입니다.
조금더 상세히 알려줄수 있습니까?

Comment: The JSON in the question is incomplete. If there are items without a `title` key make the struct member optional, see the edit.